# fetch multiple data from google sheet to telegram bot

Tags: google-apps-script, telegram-bot

i'm new to google app script trying to make a fetch data from google sheet to telegram bot

case :

i successfuly use a script which can fetch only 1 sheet row data from google sheet to telegram bot (by certain command)

Here's data fetch from gsheet to telegram
[fetch data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45VDw.jpg)

Here's data in google sheet

[data google sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PH16w.jpg)

however how to fetch multiple same data **(R1H 32005 (No.10)) based on picture**
from google sheet not only 1 sheet row to telegram bot but multiple data?

what is the script?

however this is my script

```
var token = "6219214920:AAFaDPnba36-kyFjjhK3TBp4nBtDDKEXh-M";
var SheetID = "1LirEQ5nky1Jpp6aHMfTbJ3LV7qsvfTrWa_lwTrzOpYE";

function doPost(e) {
  var stringJson = e.postData.getDataAsString();
  var updates = JSON.parse(stringJson);
 
    if(updates.message.text){
      sendText(updates.message.chat.id,CariBarangDariIDSheet(updates.message.text)); 
    }
}

function AmbilSheet1(){
  var rangeName = 'Sheet1!A2:P';
  var rows = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(SheetID, rangeName).values;
  return rows;
}


function CariBarangDariIDSheet(IDbarang){
  var dataBarang = AmbilSheet1(); 
  for (var row = 0; row < dataBarang.length; row++) {
    if(dataBarang[row][2]==IDbarang){ 
      return "Tanggal : " + dataBarang[row][0] + "\n" +
             "Area Kerja : " + dataBarang[row][1] + "\n" + 
             "Nomor Urut dan Seri Forklift : " + dataBarang[row][2] + "\n" + 
             "Kebersihan Forklift : " + dataBarang[row][3] + "\n" + 
             "APAR (Jarum Hijau & Expired) : " + dataBarang[row][4] + "\n" + 
             "Ban (Gundul), Roda, Baut Roda : " + dataBarang[row][5] + "\n" + 
             "Selang & Sambungan Hidrolik  : " + dataBarang[row][6] + "\n" + 
             "SILO Forklift : " + dataBarang[row][7] + "\n" + 
             "Kabel Accu, Socket : " + dataBarang[row][8] + "\n" + 
             "Lampu(Halo Zone, Sorot, Sirine) : " + dataBarang[row][9] + "\n" + 
             "Setir, klakson, tuas kontrol, kursi : " + dataBarang[row][10] + "\n" + 
             "Rem Jalan, Rem Parkir, Accelerator, Buzzer (Alarm Mundur) : " + dataBarang[row][11] + "\n" + 
             "Scratch (Samping Kanan) : " + dataBarang[row][12] + "\n" + 
             "Scratch (Samping Kiri) : " + dataBarang[row][13] + "\n" + 
             "Scratch (belakang) : " + dataBarang[row][14] + "\n" + 
             "Keterangan tambahan  : " + dataBarang[row][15];
    }
  }

  var dataBarang = AmbilSheet2(); 
  for (var row = 0; row < dataBarang.length; row++) {
    if(dataBarang[row][0]==IDbarang){ 
      return "Nama barang : " + dataBarang[row][0] + "\n" +
             "Harga barang : " + dataBarang[row][2] + "\n" + 
             "Jumlah Persediaan  : " + dataBarang[row][1];
    }
  }
  return "Barang tidak ditemukan." +"\n"+ "Mungkin persediaan sudah habis.";
}

function sendText(chatid,text,replymarkup){
var data = {
    method: "post",
    payload: {
      method: "sendMessage",
      chat_id: String(chatid),
      text: text,
      parse_mode: "HTML",
      reply_markup: JSON.stringify(replymarkup)
    }
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.telegram.org/bot' + token + '/', data);
}
```